# How to expand graphql fragments in order to make it more readable

Tags: graphql, text-editor, graphql-playground

I have to work with a bunch of graphql queries in the graphql playground, that get really convoluted like so:

```
query SomeQuery{
    someField
    someOtherField
    ...someTopLevelFragment
    ...someOtherTopLevelFragment
}
fragment someTopLevelFragment on SomeType{
    ...someNestedFragment
    someFieldName
    someOtherField
}
fragment someNestedFragment{
    ...someEvenMoreNestedFragment
    totallyUnrelatedField{
         anotherFieldExample
    }
}
# and so on...
```

However after a couple of nested fragments, readability hurts a bit... is there anyway, (looking for either a tool or technique) to easily replace a fragment reference for the expanded fragment, I just want to be able to quickly do some replacements every now and then for some graphql analysis.